# How do I know if the data I pushed or pinged is received? in .net

Tags: push, ping

I do not know if my question is correct but can you guys help me with my code. I pinged(dont know if that's the correct term for that) a website let's say samplewebite.com (just a sample) using the code below. Now what will I insert or what code do I have to insert or what do I have to do to check if that webite received the data i pushed or did I pushed the data with this code? please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string username = this.txtUsername.Text;
string password = this.txtPassword.Text;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
client.DownloadString("http://samplewebite.us/");
}
this.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clarify your question: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you are asking for...

Your code is issuing an HTTP GET request to the site, if the response from the server is an HTTP 200 OK (or another success code) then the DownloadString call returns the body of the response.
Otherwise (HTTP 4XX / 5XX or timeouts) it throws a WebException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx